# Jenkins build only for develop branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job which uses a Jenkinsfile stored in the repo.
I have enabled the github webhook in the Github enterprise hosted repo.

At the moment the job is triggered every time a git push is sent to any branch in the repo.
We are only looking for it to be triggered when there is a push to the develop branch.Below is the job config..

```
Build when a change is pushed to GitHub: Enabled  
Pipeline from SCM
Repository URL: my_git_repo.git
Branches to Build: */develop
Script Path: Jenkinsfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with GitLab and Jenkins by creating a REST API server using Flask. I used a GitLab webhook to send a request to the REST API server. The REST API server parsed the request from GitLab and used the Jenkins REST API to build a parameterized Pipeline job. The REST API server parsed the branch from the GitLab request and passed it as a parameter to the Jenkins job.

You could modify this solution for your own needs by modifying the REST API server to ignore requests to build anything but the "develop" branch.